# Reuniting similar classes with different templates

Tags: java, oop, templates, javafx, design-patterns

#### Context

I want to create color maps for my JavaFX application in order to display a grid with different colours according to their value. Two types are defined: `DiscreteColorMap` which uses *integer* keys and `ContinuousColorMap` with *double* keys. Both must implement the interface `ColorMap`, so that it can be called like that:

```
ColorMap palette1 = new DiscreteColorMap();
ColorMap palette2 = new ContinuousColorMap();
```

#### Problem

As both classes rely on the same interface, I specify a template (`public interface ColorMap<T>`) in order to adapt to each of them:

```
ColorMap<Integer> palette1 = new DiscreteColorMap();
ColorMap<Double> palette2 = new ContinuousColorMap();
```

I want the simplest syntax for color maps so I need to get rid of the `<Integer>` and `<Double>` strings. What is the most elegant way to do that?

#### Source

The complete code can be found in this [GitHub project](https://github.com/MartiniDry/Mazette/tree/master/src/com/rosty/util/colormap).

#### EDIT

My English is not perfect ^^ I used "to get rid of" but this is not clear: when I instantiate my color maps, I want to make `<Integer>` and `<Double>` disappear, so I could write `ColorMap palette...` instead of `ColorMap<Integer> palette...`.

Comment: `Number` is the superclass of both `Integer` and `Double`, using `<Number>` should work for both.

Comment: `<Integer>` and `<Double>` here are not strings. It’s not really clear what you’re asking. Why do you want to “get rid of them”?

Comment: The type parameters are optional, you can write: `ColorMap cm = new DiscreteColorMap();`. This uses what is termed a “raw type”. But you lose specific type info, so it is not recommended to use raw types. IDEs will highlight them and recommend adding the type parameter back again.

Comment: You have two classes that use different types. You want to abstract those classes as a common base class. This is exactly the situation that generics is for. Why do you want to get rid of the type arguments (the `<Integer>` and `<Double>` bits)? What would you like instead?

Comment: @SephB Could there be a problem if we use `Number` instead of a template? With this solution we could instantiate a `DiscreteColorMap` using `double` or `long`, and I want to work with `int` exclusively

Comment: @James_D I'm pointing out the syntax problem for my instruction : `ColorMap<Integer> cm = new DiscreteColorMap();`. I want my line of code to be as short as possible, which is why I don't talk about templates but simply the words in the line.

Comment: @jewelsea Could it create runtime errors or something like this if we don't explicit the type?

Comment: @Slaw I thought I could "hide" `Integer` and `Double` from the lines of code to avoid redundancy with the class names (`Discrete` and `Continuous`).

Comment: you seem to be looking for something like an "inverse diamond operator" - that is having a field typed super (which has a type parameter) infer its actual type from a sub (which has a fixed type) .. as far as I know, that's not supported. Could you side-step by using var?

Comment: As noted, if `ColorMap` is generic, then omitting the `<Integer>` (or similar) makes it a raw type, and you should avoid raw types at all costs. So, if you're using `ColorMap<Integer>` as a _field_, then I don't see any way to legitimately omit the type argument. A _local variable_, however, could use `var pallet = new DiscreteColorMap();` (though note that makes the type of `pallet` the subtype `DiscreteColorMap`, instead of the base type `ColorMap`).

Comment: "Could it create runtime errors or something like this if we don't explicit the type?" -> Declaring a raw type does not create a runtime error, but it allows later runtime errors that would otherwise be caught at compile time. `ColorMap cm = new DiscreteColorMap(); cm.delete(2.0);` will not be flagged as a compile error like it would if the definition was `ColorMap<Integer>`.  Generally, catching such errors at compile time is preferred, hence raw types are not recommended.  Note the var case is different as it infers type information rather than omitting it.

Comment: I’m assuming what you’re asking here is how to assign objects of type `DiscreteColorMap` and `ContinuousColorMap` to references of the same type (in a non-trivial way). It also depends why you want to do that.

Comment: @SephB Note that while `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`, `ColorMap<Integer>` is not a subclass of `ColorMap<Number>` (which makes sense if you think about it in the right way). So you can't do `ColorMap<Number> palette = new DiscreteColorMap();`. You have to do `ColorMap<? extends Number> palette = new DiscreteColorMap();`, which limits what you can then do with `palette`.

Comment: You can assign both of these to references of type `ColorMap<?>` or `ColorMap<? extends Number>`, which may or may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL/DR:

There are three ways to remove the type parameters from the type of the reference variable:

1. Use `var`. This is simply a syntactic shorthand, and `var palette = new DiscreteColorMap();` is identical at both runtime and compile time to `DiscreteColorMap palette = new DiscreteColorMap();`. This is covered in another answer.
2. Use wildcards: `ColorMap<?> palette = new DiscreteColorMap();`. This tells the compiler to "forget" the type being used as the parametrized type. This means you won't be able to invoke any methods expecting parameters of type `T`, because the compiler can't check the type is correct. This is covered in detail below.
3. **(Don't do this.)** Use raw types: `ColorMap palette = new DiscreteColorMap();`. This tells the compiler to *ignore* the types of the parameters (it effectively treats `T` as `Object`). Any errors because of incompatible types are thrown at runtime and not caught at compile time, and for this reason this approach is strongly not recommended.

---

The rest of this answer describes in detail the second option, using wildcards.

---

The purpose of Java generics is to allow the flexibility to create classes which can work with any type of object (or a specific "range" of types of object), while preserving the ability of the compiler to perform compile-time type checking. The canonical example of this is the Collections API that is part of the `java.util` package.

In your case, you've defined a `ColorMap` interface which is generic, and I'm guessing from the name of the interface that you are mapping values of the parametrized type `T` to colors. So you probably have something like this:

```
public interface ColorMap<T> {
    public Color get(T value);
}
```

And then some implementations. I'm going to use very basic implementations which are not production-level, just to demonstrate the idea. There is one for values of `Integer` type:

```
public class DiscreteColorMap implements ColorMap<Integer> {

    private final Color[] colors ;

    public DiscreteColorMap(Color... colors) {
        this.colors = colors ;
    }

    @Override
    public Color get(Integer value) {
        return colors[value];
    }
}
```

and one of type `Double`:

```
public class ContinuousColorMap implements ColorMap<Double> {

    private final Color start ;
    private final Color end ;

    public ContinuousColorMap(Color start, Color end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public Color get(Double value) {
        return start.interpolate(end, value);
    }
}
```

Note that *as far as the compiler is concerned*, `ColorMap<Integer>` and `ColorMap<Double>` are distinct types.

As far as I can tell, your question seems to be "Can I create a `DiscreteColorMap` and `ContinuousColorMap` and assign them to references of the same type". The answer is "yes", and you can do this in a non-trivial way (i.e. not just assigning them to `Object` references) using wildcards:

```
ColorMap<?> cm1 = new DiscreteColorMap(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
ColorMap<?> cm2 = new ContinuousColorMap(Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
```

The reference type `ColorMap<?>` can be thought of as "A `ColorMap` of some specific, but unknown, type". (I think of `ColorMap<Integer>` as "A `ColorMap` of type `Integer`", etc.)

You can also use *bounded* wild cards. Since both `Integer` and `Double` are subclasses of `Number`, you can specify that in the types:

```
ColorMap<? extends Number> cm1 = new DiscreteColorMap(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
ColorMap<? extends Number> cm2 = new ContinuousColorMap(Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
```

The way to think of `ColorMap<? extends Number>` is "A `ColorMap` of some specific type that is `Number` or a subclass of `Number`". Here `Number` is an *upper bound* for the parametrized type.

With the current interface and class definitions you have, this is the most specific way to "unite" the types of the two different color maps: they are both `ColorMap`s of some type that is a subclass of `Number`.

Whether or not any of this is useful depends on what you want to do with the `ColorMap`s. You can certainly do

```
List<ColorMap<? extends Number>> colorMaps = List.of(cm1, cm2);
```

The problem here is that the only method you have in `ColorMap` *consumes* values of the parametrized type (i.e. the `get(...)` method expects a parameter of type `T`). Since the actual type for each `ColorMap` in our list is unknown (we only know it is some *specific* subclass of `Number`), the compiler cannot infer that we are passing the correct value to any given instance of a `ColorMap<? extends Number>`. One of our instances specifically needs to be passed an `Integer`, the other specifically needs to be passed a `Double`. Since there's no value that can be both of these things, we can't write any code like:

```
Number value = 1;
for (ColorMap<? extends Number> cm : colorMaps) {
    // this won't compile, because cm expects some specific type of Number:
    Color c = cm.get(value);
}
```

This next part is a little artificial in this case, but if `ColorMap` had a method that *produced* (i.e. returns) values of type `T`, then this list might be useful. It's not clear how you would implement this, but if you added a method to the interface:

```
public interface ColorMap<T> {
    public Color get(T value);
    public T getValue(Color c);
}
```

Then you could do:

```
List<ColorMap<? extends Number>> colorMaps = List.of(cm1, cm2);
Color c = Color.BLUE;
for (ColorMap<? extends Number> cm : colorMaps) {
    Number value = cm.getValue(c);
}
```

This will compile. The complier is assured that each `ColorMap` in our list has a specific value of `T` that is `Number` or a subclass of `Number`. Therefore each `getValue()` method returns some kind of `Number`, and the assignment `Number value = cm.getValue(c);` is guaranteed to succeed.

If you change the definition of `ContinuousColorMap` a little, then there may be a nice way to use a common type without the artificial `getValue()` method:

```
public interface ColorMap<T> {
    public Color get(T value);
}
```

```
public class DiscreteColorMap implements ColorMap<Integer> {

    private final Color[] colors ;

    public DiscreteColorMap(Color... colors) {
        this.colors = colors ;
    }

    @Override
    public Color get(Integer value) {
        return colors[value];
    }
}
```

This time, make `ContinuousColorMap` a `ColorMap<Number>`:

```
public class ContinuousColorMap implements ColorMap<Number> {

    private final Color start ;
    private final Color end ;

    public ContinuousColorMap(Color start, Color end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public Color get(Number value) {
        return start.interpolate(end, value.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Now we can do

```
ColorMap<? super Integer> cm1 = new DiscreteColorMap(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
ColorMap<? super Integer> cm2 = new ContinuousColorMap(Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
List<ColorMap<? super Integer>> colorMaps = List.of(cm1, cm2);
```

Here `Integer` is a *lower bound* for the parametrized type, and we can interpret `ColorMap<? super Integer>` as "A `ColorMap` of some specific type which is an `Integer` or a superclass of `Integer`". Since `Number` is a superclass of integer, the assignment for `cm2` compiles.

For every element in the list, the `get(...)` method expects some specific type, but we know that specific type must be either an `Integer` or a superclass of `Integer`. So if we pass in an `Integer`, that call is guaranteed to succeed. Consequently, we can do

```
Integer value = 1;
for (ColorMap<? super Integer> cm : colorMaps) {
    // this line will compile and retrieve the correct color when executed:
    Color c = cm.get(value);
}
```

---

This is probably now way beyond the scope of the question, but if you want you can even write a class that keeps track of `ColorMap` instances according to their type, and given a `Number` will return a color from the color map for the specific type of number provided. To do this, you use the `Class<T>` class as a "type token":

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ColorMaps {

    private final Map<Class<? extends Number>, ColorMap<? extends Number>> colorMaps = new HashMap<>();

    public <N extends Number> void registerColorMap(Class<N> type, ColorMap<N> map) {
        colorMaps.put(type, map);
    }

    public <N extends Number> ColorMap<N> getColorMap(Class<N> type) {
        return (ColorMap<N>) colorMaps.get(type);
    }

    public <N extends Number> Color getColor(N n) {
        Class<N> type = (Class<N>) n.getClass();
        return getColorMap(type).get(n);
    }
}
```

And then you can do fun things like:

```
ColorMaps colorMaps = new ColorMaps();
colorMaps.registerColorMap(Integer.class, 
    new DiscreteColorMap(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE));
colorMaps.registerColorMap(Double.class,
    new ContinuousColorMap(Color.RED, Color.BLUE));

List<Number> numbers = List.of(0, 0.5, 1, 1.0, 2);
for (Number n : numbers) {
    System.out.println(n.getClass());
    System.out.println(colorMaps.getColor(n));
}
```

This code will use the `DiscreteColorMap` to map the integers in the list (`0`, `1`, and `2`), and the `ContinuousColorMap` to map the doubles in the list (`0.5` and `1.0`).

Comment: I'm impressed by the quality of the answer, thanks to you and @StepUp for your explanations :) Effectively the scope of my question is way beyond the last part of the answer (this is a little app for pedagogical purposes) but it gives a good idea; I will add pre-defined color maps in my application after v1.0 is launched.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get rid of variable type declaration, then you use `var`:

```
var palette1 = new DiscreteColorMap();
var palette2 = new ContinuousColorMap();
```

[As openjdk says:](https://openjdk.org/projects/amber/guides/lvti-faq)

> The role of var in a local variable declaration is to stand in for the
> type, so that the name and initializer stand out: `var person = new Person();` The compiler infers the type of the local variable from the
> initializer. This is especially worthwhile if the type is
> parameterized with wildcards, or if the type is mentioned in the
> initializer. Using var can make code more concise without sacrificing
> readability, and in some cases it can improve readability by removing
> redundancy.

**UPDATE:**

Special thanks to [jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea) and [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw):

- `var` cannot be used for field declarations
- `var` will infer a type of the subclass, not the superclass.

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for clarification! I misunderstood question. Please, see my updated answer

Comment: I think it is worth adding some of the additional info from Slaw's comment, i.e., `var` cannot be used for field declarations and it will infer a type of the subclass, not the superclass.

Comment: @jewelsea yeah, thank you, it is very worthful information. Please, see my updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know about the `var` keyword, in fact I've never used more than Java 8 to create my applications :) Thanks for this proposal, even if it doesn't exactly answer my problem this is an interesting alternative